# Facebook images are not shown in ios version of cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, cross-domain

I'd like to display the facebook profile image when a user had logged in via facebook. The images from the domain graph.facebook.com are not shown in the ios version of my app. It works fine in browser and android as well.
I added the access rules (I'm using meteor)

```
App.accessRule("*"); 
App.accessRule("graph.facebook.com");
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you found any solution?  I have the same issue...

Comment: No, I download the images to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was caused because I was referencing the Facebook images inside my app with an 'http' link when my server site was running on a secure site 'https'.  iOS had blocked all links to insecure sites inside a secure site.

The solution was change the fb links to https:

`https://graph.facebook.com/10154217231etc....`

Actually FB serves his resources in both http and https sites.